# Pandas While Loop Based On Condition - Truth Value Of A Series Is Ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop

I have two dataframes. They both contain the same columns.

data = pd.DataFrame({'old_name': [2, 1], 'new_name': [2, 3], 'start':['2021-05-20', '2008-08-01'], 'end': ['2021-08-08', '2021-05-20']})

old_name  new_name  start      end
2         2         2021-05-20 2021-08-08
1         3         2008-08-01 2022-05-20

base = pd.DataFrame({'old_name': [3], 'new_name': [3], 'start':['2021-05-19'], 'end': ['2022-12-31'})

old_name  new_name  start      end
3         3         2021-05-19 2022-12-31

I am trying to create a new df that takes a new name df "base" and goes back in time finding all the old names and linking them together in descending date order while having the old name's end date >= the start date of the new name. There can be more than one match between old and new name and I have to follow the trail for all of them until start < '2008-08-01'.

The final result should be:
old_name  new_name  start      end
3         3         2021-05-19 2022-12-31
1         3         2008-08-01 2022-05-20

```
data['start'] = pd.to_datetime(data['start'])
base['start'] = pd.to_datetime(base['start'])
data['start'] = pd.to_datetime(data['start'])
base['start'] = pd.to_datetime(base['start'])

begin_date = datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 1)
list = pd.DataFrame(columns=base.columns)
for index, row in base.iterrows():
     start_date = row['start']
     base_name = row['name']

     while start_date > begin_date:
          temp = data[(data['new_name'] == base_name) & (data['end'] >= start_date)].copy().reset_index(drop=True)
          start_date = data['start']

     list = pd.concat([list, temp], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
     del temp

I get a "Truth value of a series is ambiguous" but I can't seem to find where I can correct my code. The condition evaluates to True so I'm stuck. Can someone please help me get back on track? Please let me know if my question isn't clear. Thank you!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code might be erroring out at the line,

```
 while start_date > begin_date:
```

In this line, you are trying to compare a pandas series(start_date) with begin_date which is not a series, it is a scalar value.

An easy fix would be,

```
while start_date.values[index] > begin_date:
```

Answer (score 0):

In first row under the while you access a DataFrame column which is a Series, then you compare it with something. For example data['new_name'] is a Series.

Comment: It seems like your answer is going in the right direction. How would I change my code so it works?

Comment: Sorry initially I was wrong the first line of the while is good. 
It is still very foggy to me what you try to achieve, so I cannot write it for you. What I can tell you is the error comes from the while's condition after the first iteration: 
First both are datetimes, then at the end of the while body you update the start_date to be a Series. This results in start_date > begin_date (a series vs. a datetime results in a boolean Series) for which the truth value is ambiguous, hence the error. Hope this helps.